# Root view is not showing in the middle of the screen

Tags: ios, xib

I am new in iOS. I have created a xib file for `MyViewController`. In the xib file, I added an `UIView` as the **root** view of my controller, on top of that is an `UIDatePicker` and an `UIButton`.

After I made proper connections to my controller. I run my app. But the layout is not in the middle:

[image]

Why? How to make it show properly on screen?

Comment: Are you setting up required auto layout constraints?

Comment: What is "required" auto layout constraints? What are the values?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set autolayout constraints. Or springs and struts to keep it centre.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set autolayout constraints and you can use them in this way.
Fir Click on UIDatePicker on Storyboard and find the **PIN** button which is at the right bottom of the screen and is second from right. I have shown a picture of how it looks
[image]

For the UIDatePicker provide the constraints as follows as given in the picture.
[image]

Provide
**Leading Space** = 0
**Trailing Space** = 0
 
**Vertical Spacing** = 25 // You can change this depending on your needs

Now for the UIButton you can have these constraints

[image]

From UIButton Right Click and drag to UIDatePicker and choose **Vertical Spacing** and **Center Horizontally** and add the constraints as shown in the picture

Comment: Can I add constrains only in the root view where date picker and button have been added? Do I really need to add autolayout constraint in every single UI element added on root view?

Comment: No, There is only a single storyboard which is maintained for all devices. Use the size class as any X any. If you are having troubles in that, check some of my videos which i did for autolayout
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xGeBiWUiYnI . Check the complete tutorial series

Comment: @user842225 If you find them useful and as a sol to your answer, you can please accept as a tick. Thanks